# How do I fix this error with creating a virtual table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a virtual table in that will allow me to look up values in the alias field of the *_categories table, when I only have access to the category id in the scope of the view I'm working in. (not sure if those are all the right terms).

In the *_categories table, the id is in the id column, in the *_content table, the category id is in the catid column.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
CREATE VIEW articles AS SELECT article.*,
category.alias AS category_alias,
FROM s5vuq_content AS article LEFT JOIN s5vuq_categories AS category ON category.'id' = article.'catid'
```

But I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘FROM s5vuq_content AS article
LEFT JOIN s5vuq_categories AS category ON
catego’ at line 3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your problem is the VIEW. Searches against Views in MySQL cannot utilise the underlying indexes. Don't bother with views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a typo, but since you have many of them, I am posting this answer.  Here is your corrected query:

```
CREATE VIEW articles AS
SELECT article.*, category.alias AS category_alias   -- I removed a comma here
FROM s5vuq_content AS article
LEFT JOIN s5vuq_categories AS category
    ON category.id = article.catid;        -- column names don't take single quotes
```

In addition to the dangling comma at the end of the `SELECT` statement, you were also placing the column names in the `ON` clause in single quotes.  Single quotes are mainly used for string literals in SQL.  If you needed to escape column names in MySQL, you could use either double quotes or backticks.  So, both of the following should be valid:

```
ON category."id" = article."catid"
ON category.`id` = article.`catid`
```

Comment: Hi Tim, a follow-on question if you don't mind... I've realised I need to add in a couple of additional columns from the same tables into the same view.

I've tried replicating the above query with ALTER VIEW, but not getting very far.

Comment: You should open a new question.